# How to autocomplete path using alias root?

Tags: autocompletion, path

I'm working on frontend project, we're using root alias, like:

`import from '~/src/components/button';`

instead of:

`import from '../../../../../components/button';`

But when I try to import from `~/`, my `nvim` is not able to autocomplete the path.

How can I let my nvim to know from where it should suggest the path?

Comment: This is a bit vague but perhaps you're issue is with the `~`. Depending on the context,  to get `~` to resolve you have to use `expand('~/some/file')` rather than just `'~/some/file'`.

Comment: oh! actually I defined `~` as my project root, but I can redefine it to `@/` or something else.

Comment: How/where did you alias the path? (Regardless, `~` is probably a bad choice because of the confusion with home dir `~`.)